# Unable run Powershell Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

This is my first foray into Powershell. When I run a Powershell script I get the following error message:

```
PS D:\modules\setup-azure> Setup-Azure
Setup-Azure : The term 'Setup-Azure' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Setup-Azure
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Setup-Azure:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS D:\modules\setup-azure> Setup-Azure.psm
Setup-Azure.psm : The term 'Setup-Azure.psm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Setup-Azure.psm
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Setup-Azure.psm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS D:\modules\setup-azure>
```

Can someone please shed some light on the error message?

Comment: `ipmo D:\modules\setup-azure`

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: `.psm` is not script to run. It is module to import.

Comment: `ipmo` is an alias for `Import-Module`. For more information run `Get-Help ipmo` in PowerShell.

Comment: But I have the module to import

Comment: yes but you have to import the module first before you can use the commands of that module. `Import-Module D:\modules\setup-azure`, then you can use the commands of the setup-azure module

Comment: Ahhhhhhh.. thank you I will that a try and let you know how I get on. Cheers

Comment: Hello SimonS, I moved the folders and scripts to my C:.. Now when I execute the command you suggested I get the following error: PS C:\> Import-Module C:\modules\setup-azure
Import-Module : File C:\modules\setup-azure\setup-azure.psm1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disab
led on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more d
At line:1 char:14
+ Import-Module C:\modules\setup-azure
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleC

Comment: OK, the Setup-Azure module is working but now I'm getting the following error:

Comment: Which lab do you want to set up? Type a number from 1 - 11:   
The lab you want to set up is: Lab 2

Is this is correct? Y/N?:   The lab to set up is: Lab 2
Start-Transcript : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IncludeInvocationHeader'.
At D:\modules\setup-azure\setup-Azure.psm1:40 char:89
+     Start-Transcript -Path "D:\Logs\Setup-Azure-$labnumber.log" -

Comment: I couldn't show you all the error message due to limitations on the number of characters allowed in stackexchange

Comment: @Carltonp [edit] your question and add the extra information. Don't do it in the comments.